# Регулярное выражение для чисел с разделителем (к примеру 1_000)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, числа

Возникла задача проверять, имеет ли число разделитель, если имеет, возвращать `true`, соответственно сам литерал тоже должен быть валидным. Попытался сделать вот так:

```js
const reSeparatedLiteral = /^\d(_{1,1}|\d)+\d$/
const data = [{
  str: '1_000',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '10_00',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '1_0_0_0',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '_1_000',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1_000_',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1__000',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1000',
  expected: false,
}]

test(reSeparatedLiteral)

function test(re) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let currentData = data[i]
    let { str, expected } = currentData

    if(re.test(str) === expected) {
      console.log('✅ Test is passed!', str)
    } else {
      console.log('❌ Test is not passed!', str)
    }
  }
}
```

В данном случае у меня возникло две проблемы:

1. Как проверять, что число точно имеет разделитель? (Несовсем уверен как работать с аналогом оператор AND в регулярных варжения (я про это: `(?=...)(?=...)`), но уверен, что эту проблему можно решить используя подобную запись)
2. Как проверять, что разделитель это только один символ, а не два?

Про первую проблему. Я попытался делать что-то типа такого: `/(?=^\d(_{1,1}|\d)+\d$)(?=^[\D]+$)/`, но из-за этого, ни первая, ни вторая строка не проходят проверку.

**Важное уточнение**: нужно использовать исключительно регулярное выражение, то есть использование строковых методов, не вариант.

P.S. такие числа (литералы) по настоящему поддерживаются в JavaScript, то есть вы можете записать миллион в таком виде: `1_000_000`, чтобы сделать его (число) более читаемым.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8Ycmwk/1

Comment: `/^(d+_)+\d+$/` просто и банально не подходит разве?

Comment: Не совсем ясно, сколько должно быть цифр в числе, 2 или 3? Тогда `^\d{2,3}_\d{2,3}$`. Если `_` может повторяться сколько угодно раз, ``^\d{2,3}(?:_\d{2,3})+$``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а почему `\d{2,3}` ограничений на количество цифр не задано в вопросе

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew если мы про JS, то сколько угодно, хоть 1, хоть 100.

Comment: @splash58 не подходит, не проходит второй кейс.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не проходит от первого, по третий кейс.

Comment: @ΝNL993  а я и не гланул, что можно произвольное кол-во цифр меду разделителями :)

Comment: @NNL993 https://regex101.com/r/RRGIoj/1

Comment: @splash58 к сожалению нет, не подходит, выражение также не проходит второй тест.

Comment: а что вы называете вторым тестом? 10_00 проходит

Comment: @ΝNL993 проходит если опечатку исправить (`d` → `\d`), так же как и вариант @splash58

Comment: @splash58 и вправду проходит, не то запустил.

Comment: @splash58 если можете, опубликуйте свой ответ, вместе с объяснением того почему он работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Что не так с `^\d(_{1,1}|\d)+\d$`**? Строка, соответствующая выражения, должна начинаться с цифры, за которой должен следовать один или более повторов цифры или знака подчёркивания, а потом цифра в конце строки. Обратите внимание, что `{1,1}` можно всегда удалять, `^\d(_{1,1}|\d)+\d$` = `^\d(_|\d)+\d$` = `^\d[_\d]+\d$`.

**Решение**

```
^\d+(?:_\d+)+$
```

См. [пример регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/o7pg58/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d+` - одна или более цифр
- `(?:_\d+)+` - один и более повторов последовательности из `_` и одной и более цифр (из-за того, что требуется **одна и более** цифр после `_`, двойной символ подчёркивания в строке невозможен)
- `$` - конец строки.

Пример:

```js
const reSeparatedLiteral = /^\d+(?:_\d+)+$/
const data = [{
  str: '1_000',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '10_00',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '1_0_0_0',
  expected: true,
},{
  str: '_1_000',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1_000_',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1__000',
  expected: false,
},{
  str: '1000',
  expected: false,
}]

test(reSeparatedLiteral)

function test(re) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let currentData = data[i]
    let { str, expected } = currentData

    if(re.test(str) === expected) {
      console.log('✅ Test is passed!', str)
    } else {
      console.log('❌ Test is not passed!', str)
    }
  }
}
```